# There are 650 points inside a circle of radius $16$ . Prove that there exists a ring with inner radius $2$ and outer radius $3$ covering $10$ points.

Tags: combinatorics

There are 650 points inside a circle of radius $16$ . Prove that there exists  a ring with inner radius $2$ and outer radius $3$ covering $10$ points.
The solution given Problem Solving Strategies by Arthur Engel is as follows:

> We observe that point P belongs to a ring with center O iff the point O belongs to a congruent ring with center P . Thus it is sufficient to prove the following fact. If we consider all such rings with centers in the given points ,then one of these points will be covered by at least $10$ rings. These rings lie inside a circle of radius $16+3=19$ with area $19^2\pi=361\pi$ . Now, $9.361\pi=3249\pi$ ,but the sum of areas of all the rings is $650.5\pi=3250\pi$.
>
> > However, I am not getting the idea of the solution .How does this how does this imply that atleast $10$ points are covered by that ring?How does the conclusion proves the result....

Comment: There is something garbled in the solution given above.  It's certainly not true that "$9.361 \pi = 3249 \pi$" and "$650.5 \pi = 3250 \pi$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the collection of 650 rings that are centered at each one of the 650 points.

As in the solution, every one of those rings has area $5\pi$, and the total area of all rings in the collection is $3250\pi$. Because they all lie in an area of size $361\pi$, there exists a point $P$ which belongs to 10 rings in the collection.

In other words, there are points $A_1, \dots, A_{10}$ such that for every $i$ the ring centered at $A_i$ contains $P$.

However, if a point $P$ belongs to a ring centered at $Q$, it means that the distance between $P$ and $Q$ satisfies $2 \leq PQ \leq 3$. This is equivalent to $2 \leq QP \leq 3$. Point $P$ being on a ring centered at $Q$ is equivalent to point $Q$ being on a ring centered at $P$.

Therefore, there are points $A_1, \dots, A_{10}$ such that for every $i$, the ring centered at $P$ contains $A_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that there no point inside a circle of radius $19$ covered by 10 or more rings with centers in given points. Then every point of interior of a circle of radius $19$ is covered by 9 or less such rings. Then total area of all such rings should be not greater than $9\cdot S_{19}$. This is wrong, that's why suppose is wrong. Then there is at least one point covered by 10 or more rings with centers in given points. Then this point can be selected as center of ring covering 10 or more given points.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But can please say what are  you denoting by $S_{19}$ ...if $S_{19}$ denotes area of the square of rafius $19$ then , how do you make the point that if each point in the interior of the circle is covered by $9$ or less rings ,then total area of all such rings should not be greater than $9.S_{19}$ .....I did not get this part of your argument....

Comment: Let's consider division of $S_{19}$ area with rings boundaries. If we will count total area of rings we will count every part of this division not more than 9 times. That's why total area of rings must be not more that $9 S_{19}$.

Answer (score -1):

The conclusion does not prove the result.

The first thing to note here is that the ring is fixed. Therefore, we can now think about the worst case scenario. Unless I am missing anything else, we can put the points as we wish. Therefore, we can just put all the points somewhere else, let's say, in the dead center. This means that it is impossible for there to be at least 10 points.

My guess is that they are all equally spaced out, or occupies the same area, etc.

Comment: well,even if all equally spaced then...how does the result holds....